# I am trying to create a Binary Search Tree and Print the Pre-order of this tree

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to create a Binary Search Tree with the following elements in the order mentioned below:

5, 85, 89, 3, 2, 8, 65, 92

and want to Print the Pre-order of this tree.

Output should be: 5,3,2,85,8,65,89,82

This is what I got so far:

```
public class BinaryTree {
     Node root; 

     // Tree Node 
     static class Node { 
         int data; 
         Node left, right; 
         Node(int data) 
         { 
             this.data = data; 
             this.left = null; 
             this.right = null; 
         } 
     } 

     // Function to insert nodes in level order 
     public Node insertLevelOrder(int[] arr, Node root, 
                                                 int i) 
     { 
         // Base case for recursion 
         if (i < arr.length) { 
             Node temp = new Node(arr[i]); 
             root = temp; 

             // insert left child 
             root.left = insertLevelOrder(arr, root.left, 
                                              2 * i + 1); 

             // insert right child 
             root.right = insertLevelOrder(arr, root.right, 
                                                2 * i + 2); 
         } 
         return root; 
     } 

     // Function to print tree nodes in InOrder fashion 

     /* Given a binary tree, print its nodes in preorder*/
     void printPreorder(Node root) 
     { 
         if (root == null) 
             return; 

         /* first print data of node */
         System.out.print(root.data + " "); 

         /* then recur on left subtree */
         printPreorder(root.left); 

         /* now recur on right subtree */
         printPreorder(root.right); 
     } 
     // Driver program to test above function 
     public static void main(String args[]) 
     { 
         BinaryTree t2 = new BinaryTree(); 
         int arr[] = { 5, 85, 89, 3, 2, 8, 65, 92}; 
         t2.root = t2.insertLevelOrder(arr, t2.root, 0); 
         t2.printPreorder(t2.root); 
     } 
    }
```

I am getting output as 5 85 3 92 2 89 8 65 which is not correct.

Comment: why do you think that preorder should be 5,3,2,85,8,65,89,82? created binary tree has 5 at root, left/child of 5 is 85 and 89, left/right child of 85 is 3 and 2, left/right child of 89 is 8 and 65, left child of 3 is 92

Comment: your code creates a simple binary tree, not a binary search tree. this sequence 5, 85, 89, 3, 2, 8, 65, 92 cannot be a level order of a binary search tree

Comment: even if it was a valid level order of a binary search tree, your `insertLevelOrder` will not necessarily produce a valid binary search tree. for example, `3,2,1` is a valid level order but your code will produce a tree with root=3 and left/right child 2 and 1 which is not a search tree

Comment: how do I create a binary search tree in order of user input or arrray?

Comment: firstly you have to know which order it is: pre/post/in/level. then you need to verify whether it is a valid order (for example in your program, the order is not a valid level order). finally you can construct a binary search tree out of given order. you may just browse for those ways in the web. note that it is possible to construct more than one binary search tree for a given inorder. pre/post/level orders give a unique tree